# Extending general relativity with torque based on quasimetrics

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, torque, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If torque is allowed to exist in the space part of the stress energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ in the Einstein field equations
$$
R_{\mu\nu}-\frac12 g_{\mu\nu} R = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}
$$
it would lead to $T_{\mu\nu}$ being asymmetric. That would require some tensor in the left hand side of the field equations to be asymmetric as well. The Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$ can hardly be generalized to become asymmetric. However the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ can become asymmetric by using a [quasimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Quasimetrics) where the symmetry criteria is dropped meaning that the distance from a to b is different from the distance from b to a. This can be further imagined as taking the gauge freedom in the Lorentz transformation to act on the speed of light, as is done in the [Sagnac effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect) where a longer distance is experienced when measuring in the direction of a motion instead of measuring against a motion. The distance is measured symmetrically in the stationary reference frame.

Space can have torque in the form of Casimir/van der Waals forces. For example:

> Somers, D.A.T., Garrett, J.L., Palm, K.J. et al. Measurement of the Casimir torque. Nature 564, [386–389](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-018-0777-8) (2018).

and

> Bing-Sui Lu, Rudolf Podgornik, van der Waals torque and force between dielectrically anisotropic layered media,
> J. Chem. Phys. 145, [044707](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4959282) (2016)

Could such an extension of the field equations be made theoretically and tried on a real physical situation?

Comment: You may want to look into [Finsler geometry,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold) though not all Finsler structures arise from quasimetrics.